# aligned Icon on left input

Tags: css

I have a problem that I want to solve,the date icon when I set the alignment to the left does not move the icon tried all the ways and no benefit but work with me transform but it needs to reponsive on all screen and I must do it for all screens

```css
.zsg-cp,
.zsg-datepicker-wrapper {
  position: relative
}

.zsg-datepicker-wrapper .zsg-datepicker-link {
  color: #006AFF;
  font-size: 1.34em;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  top: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="zsg-datepicker-wrapper">
  <input name="dateField" type="text" value="" id="cal1DateField" min="2019-08-22" max="2020-08-22" class="zsg-datepicker">
  <a id="wrapper" style="text-align:left;left:0;float:left;transform: translateX(50px);" href="" class="zsg-datepicker-link"><span class="zsg-icon-calendar"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add full code for css as well, not just html.

Comment: Why the inline CSS? Don't be afraid to put it where it belongs - into your Stylesheet.

Comment: Also, you have a non runnable example, and you didn't neither say where exactly should the icon be...

Comment: this photo i want
https://imgur.com/6M7o53f

Comment: The code worked and corrected it above, but the text of the date came down next to me and I want the text date to be right

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your own CSS classes 
[image]

```css
.input-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icon {
  padding: 10px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  min-width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.input-field {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<form>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Date" name="dateField">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar icon"></i>
  </div>
</form>
```